# Изменение атрибутов файла

Tags: c, файлы

Знаю, что в Си есть функция `SetFileAttributes`, которая позволяет установить ОДИН какой-то конкретный атрибут, например, HIDDEN или READONLY, а все остальные атрибуты меняет на NORMAL. Вопрос такой, как изменить несколько атрибутов сразу? В документации по этой функции пишут, что можно через `||`, но это не работает. Спасибо!

Comment: Посмотрите на всякий случай в справочник про отличие операторов `|` и `||`. Кстати, функция эта не из библиотеки С, а из [Win32 API](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/fileapi/nf-fileapi-setfileattributesa).

Comment: @Harry, оператор ```|``` исправил ситуацию , спасибо большое!

Comment: В си нет такой функции, это функция из WinAPI

Comment: @こきん, Да, я уже это понял, спасибо